# ASP.NET GridView - Datatable jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

I have a problem with my datagridview and datatable jquery paginator.

So, I bind my grid with some data and the paginator only show one number at a time. Sample:

Total number of records: 50

First 2 disabled, Last 2 enabled
<< < 1 > >>

I press next button and... all buttons enabled
<< < 2 > >>

Images

[image: First load of the datagrid]

[image: When I press next button]

I really don't know why this happens.

Here is the code to build the datatable at client side.

```
var previous = "&lt;"; var next = ">"; var first = "»"; var last = "«";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tableID").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": previous,
                "sNext": next,
                "sLast": first,
                "sFirst": last
            },
            "sEmptyTable": "No results",
            "sZeroRecords": "No results"
        },
        "sCookiePrefix": "MyCoooierefdgfix_tableID",
        "bStateSave": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "iDisplayLength": parseInt(pageSize),
        "bDestroy": true
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Actually I can't because the application structure is too complex. Too much CSS, and javascript code :/ Sorry

Comment: It's because it's not clear what's happening, can you provide some images?

Comment: Is the data in the table being loaded via Ajax? I've had this problem before when using ajax and not passing the iTotalRecords parameter.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: images included

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I am not using Ajax

Comment: I believe this is due to the plugin not being able to determine how many rows are in the table, and therefore how many pages there are. Exactly why this is happening is hard to say.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Is there any way to know how much lines the plugin thinks that the table has? Maybe debugging?

Comment: Does your datagridview render the "theader" and "tbody" tags? I noticed those were being rendered in the link that Nicola provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've set-up a fiddle for you and everything works correctly. You can look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Bma8/). Maybe you have an error in your html and so the plugin cannot calculate the correct number of rows, that's the only thing i can think of.

EDIT - i can replicate your problem by adding this line of CSS as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Bma8/1/). Are you sure it's not happening something like that?

```
span span.paginate_button{
  display:none;  
}
```